# Compound Component for Storybook Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, storybook

Trying to write a simple compound component - a `select` component  that contains an array of `option` components, but failing and not sure where the issue is.

( I've used https://storybook.js.org/tutorials/intro-to-storybook/react/en/composite-component/ for a starting point )

Select Component

```
import Option from "./Option";

export default function Select({ options, label, elementID, size, disabled }) {
    return (
        <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor={elementID}>{label}</label>
            <select className={`form-control ${size}`} id={elementID} disabled={disabled ? disabled : false}>
                {options.map(option => (
                    <Option key={option.value}>{option.label}</Option>
                ))}
            </select>
        </div>
    )
}

Select.propTypes = {
    label:         PropTypes.string,
    elementID:     PropTypes.string,
    size:          PropTypes.oneOf(["", "form-control-sm", "form-control-lg"]),
    disabled:      PropTypes.bool,
    options:       PropTypes.array,
}
```

Select.stories

```
import React from 'react';

import Select from "../components/Select";
import * as OptionStories from "./Option.stories";

export default {
    title: "Forms/Select",
    component: Select,
}

const Template = args => <Select {...args} />;

export const Default = Template.bind({});
Default.args = {
    label: "Select Label",
    elementID: "selectID",
    options: [
        { ...OptionStories.default.args.option, value: '1', label: 'Test'},
    ],
}
```

Option Component

```
import PropTypes from "prop-types"

function Option({ label, value, disabled }) {
    return (
        <option value={value} disabled={disabled ? disabled : false}>{label}</option>
    )
}

Option.propTypes = {
    label:         PropTypes.string,
    value:         PropTypes.string,
    disabled:      PropTypes.bool,
}

export default Option
```

Option.stories

```
import Option from "../components/Option"

export default {
    title: "Option",
    component: Option,
}

const Template = args => <Option {...args} />

export const Basic = Template.bind({})
Basic.args = {
    option: {
        value: "0",
        label: "Select Label",
    },
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out thanks to https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-list-component/

For anyone interested, the `option` component and story wasn't needed.

In the `select` component I changed the return to

```
                {options.map(item => {
                    return <option value={item.value}>{item.label}</option>
                })}
```

And in the `select.story`

```
options: [
        {
            value: 'a',
            label: 'First Option'
        },
    ],
```